# What is "packagekitd" and how do I make the Software Updater stop waiting for it?

Tags: updates

I usually run the Software Updater when I switch on my desktop each morning. *Very* often I sit and wait while it displays this message:

> waiting for packagekitd to exit

And looks like this:

[image]

I've done some websearching on this, and in spite of a couple mentions on Unix.SE, I haven't succeeded in finding out what "packagekitd" is, why I "wait" for it so often (can be a matter of minutes, not seconds), and **whether I can avoid this somehow**. My goal is to prevent `packagekitd` from hijacking my updating process.

Help appreciated! I'm running plain Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/PackageKit

Comment: I've integrated the comment from muru in the only available answer. Thanks muru

Comment: 2023 and I just faced this exact same issue. Luckily this post contained the solution!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

PackageKit is a system made to use the distribution's software installation and update tools easier. You can read more about it here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/PackageKit/pk-intro.html

You can stop packagekitd with the command:

```
systemctl stop packagekit
```

If, for some reason, you wish to disable it, you can use:

```
systemctl disable packagekit
```

**Update for Ubuntu 22+** — the name of the service has changed to `packagekit.service` (thanks to rob74 for mentioning this).

Comment: Or if you really want to get rid of it, "sudo apt-get -s purge packagekit".  Check for dependencies, but in my case, they were non-consequential.  My final go used "sudo apt-get  purge packagekit appstream apt-config-icons" to remove the extra cruft.

Comment: solution I am looking for is to simply delay the launch of packagekit until a few minutes after a reboot not almost immediately ...   either as a parameter or by inserting a wrapper to replace its launch which just sleeps for 10 minutes before launching packagekit

Comment: @scott-stensland- You could put that stop command in crontab (@reboot) and then another "@reboot sleep 600 && systemctl start package" after that.

Comment: there is no such systemctl service on my system, but I could kill it with `sudo fuser -vik -TERM /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`

Comment: Didn't work for me, until I noticed that on my system (Ubuntu 22.04) it's called "packagekit.service". Not sure if this is because of the newer Ubuntu version, but anyway, `systemctl stop packagekit.service` did the job...

Comment: Yes, the service name has had an ".service" added to it in later versions of Ubuntu, which was not the case back when the answer was written in 2018. I'll amend the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @dave58 what do you think about these dependencies? "packagekit packagekit-tools software-properties-common ubuntu-server". The last one seems quite important so I just stopped the service.

Comment: @valerio-bozz : Yes, 'ubuntu-server' is a meta-package for your server/system.  Removing it would probably result in dire consequences...  Ditto for 'properties-common'

Comment: @valerio-bozz : [Continued - stupid StackExchange 'limits'... ]  I have found that by adding an explicit '+' to the package name, you can 'force' a package install for these critical 'dependencies.  Try a ````sudo apt-get --simulate purge  packagekit software-properties-common+ ubuntu-server+```` and see what it results in.  Note the '+' after software-properties-common and ubuntu-server. This will cause them to (be flagged as installs even though the apt-get command is 'purge' or 'remove' '
Once you are happy with the results, remove the '--simulate' ( or '-s' ) from the apt-get command.